# Why cant I clear an input field with javascript created by Yii CRUD?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

Field generated by GRUD of Yii of php:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'productId')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>`

Html of firefox:

`<input id="taolistforcreate-productid" class="form-control" name="TaolistForCreate[productId]" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" type="text">`

script used to clear the field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#taolistforcreate-productid").bind("paste",function(e){
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    var taoID=GetTaoID(pastedData);
    $("#taolistforcreate-productid").val('');//failed to clear the field 
    $("#taolistforcreate-productid").val(taoID);//succeed 
});
});
```

I've also googled bunch of other js code,still do not work.

Comment: Can you add also the code where you fire that clearing script?

Comment: You pasted here code with syntax error. Fix it, check what console says when you try to fire it, if still not working - paste fixed code again, but in question (not in comment) -  in `code` tag

Comment: code fixed and re-paste in question.

Comment: Console is empty? Did you tried `attr('value', '')` instead of `val('')`?

Comment: attr('value', '') can not work. No console err in Chrome or FF.

Comment: How about just `val(null)`?

Comment: val(null) still failed

Comment: And what's under this `taoID`? it's overriding clearing.

Answer (score 0):

could be that your access to the generated  id don't match so

You could try adding an your id to the input field

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'productId')
         ->textInput(['id' => 'your_id','maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

and in js

```
 $("#your_id").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#your_id").removeAttr("value");
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

God,finally...problem solved,after adding "return false;" into the bottom line of my personal onpaste event handling function!

The broswer actullay fires the "onpaste" event twice.After handling by my own function,the same event will be dispatched to jquery's default event handling routing,that's to say,the content of clipboard will be pasted twice,hence the problem.